# Clean way to generate random numbers from 0 to 50 of size 1000 in python, with no similar number of occurrences

Tags: python, numpy

What would be the cleanest way to generate random numbers from 0 to 50, of size 1000, with the condition that no number should have the same number of occurrence as any other number using python and numpy.

Example for size 10: [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2] --> no number occurs same number of times

Comment: Interesting. All I know is `numpy.random.default_rng().integers(0, 50+1, 1000)`, but how to cleanly guarantee that condition?

Comment: I'd probably generate 2 sequences, one for the values, one for the repetition. If all values are represented this can be done by generating to list like sequences and shuffling them. If some values are missing then use the sequences but use a method such as `numpy.random.choice` without replacement and choose however many needed.

Comment: Those constraints don't make it all that random.  Would `[random.randint(0, 50)] * 1000` be a valid solution?  Or do you want to *maximize* the number of *different* random numbers you get?  Or do you want uniqueness to be evenly distributed between the minimum and maximum possibilities?

Comment: @Samwise That'll just repeat a single random number 1000 times.

Comment: @MYousefi That's the point -- it satisfies the problem description by being random and also guaranteeing that no number occurs the same number of times.  Is that a valid solution?

Comment: That's a serious limitation.  If you have one 0, two 1s, three 2s, four 3s, etc., then by the time you get to 49 you only have 1,275 numbers to pick from.  You will need every number to be involved.

Comment: @TimRoberts: The (perhaps surprising) implication is that no more than 44 unique values can appear in the result, with (50 choose 44)*(44 choose (1000-990)) possibilities up to ordering for exactly 44.

Comment: I don't think all values are meant to be represented in the output.

Comment: @David the 50 is not relevant in this calculation. For example 45 values summing to 1000: `sum((1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 48, 49))`

Comment: @mozway: The 50 is relevant in that it contributes to the number of distinct outputs (simply by labeling the counts), including the restriction (relevant for, say, 2000 samples) that there must be no *more* than 50 terms in that sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drawing from a [`rng.dirichlet`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.dirichlet.html) distribution and rejecting samples guarantees to obey the requirements, but with low entropy for the number of unique elements. You have to adjust the range of unique elements yourself with `np.ones(rng.integers(min,max))`. If *max* approaches the maximum number of unique elements (here 50) rejection might take long or has no solution, causing an infinite loop. The code is for a resulting array of size of 100.

```
import numpy as np

times = np.array([])
rng = np.random.default_rng()

#rejection sampling
while times.sum() != 100 or len(times) != len(np.unique(times)): 
    times = np.around(rng.dirichlet(np.ones(rng.integers(5,10)))*100)

nr = rng.permutation(np.arange(51))[:len(times)]
np.repeat(nr, times.astype(int))
```

Random output

```
array([ 7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,
        7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7, 33, 33, 33,
       33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33,
       21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21,
       21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 22,
       22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 25,  5,  5,  5])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a recursive and possibly very slow implementation that produces the output desired.

```
import numpy as np


def get_sequence_lengths(values, total):
    if total == 0:
        return [[]], True
    if total < 0:
        return [], False
    if len(values) == 0:
        return [], False
    sequences = []
    result = False
    for i in range(len(values)):
        ls, suc = get_sequence_lengths(values[:i] + values[i + 1:], total - values[i])
        result |= suc
        if suc:
            sequences.extend([[values[i]] + s for s in ls])
    return sequences, result


def gen_numbers(rand_min, rand_max, count):
    values = list(range(rand_min, rand_max + 1))
    sequences, success = get_sequence_lengths(list(range(1, count+1)), count)
    sequences = list(filter(lambda x: len(x) <= 1 + rand_max - rand_min, sequences))
    if not success or not len(sequences):
        raise ValueError('Cannot generate with given parameters.')

    sequence = sequences[np.random.randint(len(sequences))]
    values = np.random.choice(values, len(sequence), replace=False)
    result = []
    for v, s in zip(values, sequence):
        result.extend([v] * s)
    return result
```

`get_sequence_length` will generate all permutations of unique positive integers that sum up to the given total. The sequence will then be further filtered by the number available values. Finally the generation of paired value and counts from the sequence produces the output.

As mentioned above `get_sequence_length` is recursive and is going to be quite slow for larger input values.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the variability of generating random combinations in a potentially long trial/error loop, you could use a function that directly produces a random partition of a number where all parts are distinct (increasing).   from that you simply need to map shuffled numbers over the chunks provided by the partition function:

```
def randPart(N,size=0):                       # O(√N)
    if not size:
        maxSize = int((N*2+0.25)**0.5-0.5)    # ∑1..maxSize <= N
        size    = random.randrange(1,maxSize) # select random size
    if size == 1: return (N,)                 # one part --> all of N 
    s = size*(size-1)//2                      # min sum of deltas for rest 
    a = random.randrange(1,(N-s)//size)       # base value
    p = randPart(N-a*size,size-1)             # deltas on other parts 
    return (a,*(n+a for n in p))              # combine to distinct parts
```

usage:

```
size = 30
n    = 10

chunks  = randPart(size)
numbers = random.sample(range(n),len(chunks))
result  = [n for count,n in zip(chunks,numbers) for _ in range(count)]

print(result)
[9, 9, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6,
 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6]

# resulting frequency counts
from collections import Counter
print(sorted(Counter(result).values()))
[3, 4, 5, 6, 12]
```

*note that, if your range of random numbers is smaller than the maximum number of distinct partitions (for example fewer than 44 numbers for an output of 1000 values), you would need to modify the randPart function to take the limit into account in its calculation of maxSize:*

```
def randPart(N,sizeLimit=0,size=0):
    if not size:
        maxSize = int((N*2+0.25)**0.5-0.5)    # ∑1..maxSize <= N
        maxSize = min(maxSize,sizeLimit or maxSize)
    ...
```

*You could also change it to force a minimum number of partitions*

Answer (score 0):

This solves your problem in the way @MYousefi suggested.

```
import random

seq = list(range(50))
random.shuffle(seq)
values = []
for n,v in enumerate(seq):
    values.extend( [v]*(n+1) )
    if len(values) > 1000:
        break
print(values)
```

Note that you can't get exactly 1,000 numbers.  At first, I generated the entire sequence and then took the first 1,000, but that means whichever sequence gets truncated will be the same length as one of the earlier ones.   You end up with 1,035.

Comment: So for 1000 numbers that won't work, there will be two times groups of 10 ;)

Comment: I think it is possible to do 1000 if and only if there exists at least one set of unique integer values such that sum of the set is 1000. You'd have to find all such sets and randomize a set from them to use as counts. The values would be simple since there's no restriction on the values, e.g., all values must appear.

Comment: I probably should mention that the condition above true for any `n > 2` since it has at least `(n-1, 1)` pair as a solution.

Comment: @mozway I mentioned that.  It's a lot more work to get exactly 1,000, but such a requirement would be ridiculous in the real world.